# How to fill in every nth row and leave above rows with zero using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Hi supposed I have a dataframe as such

```
temp <- data.frame(value = sample(c ( 1:312), 20 ), value2 = sample(c ( 1:312), 20 )  )
```

What I like to do is fill in every 3rd row with "hi" and leave the rest of the row above as either NA or 0.
I tried doing this but

```
temp$t = "hi"

temp %>%
  mutate(
    prev = lag ( t, 3 )
  )
```

but this only works for the first 3 rows then everything is back is filled with "hi" What I want is to have "hi" only appear after every 3rd row.
Ideally the first row should be "hi" as well.

thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `rep` -

```
temp$t <- rep(c('hi', NA, NA), length.out = nrow(temp))
```

If you prefer `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

temp %>%
  mutate(t = rep(c('hi', NA, NA), length.out = n()))

#   value value2    t
#1     79    105   hi
#2    292    174 <NA>
#3     82     74 <NA>
#4    192    141   hi
#5    158    140 <NA>
#6    176    240 <NA>
#7      7     33   hi
#8     10    284 <NA>
#9     48    286 <NA>
#10    94    181   hi
#11   128     22 <NA>
#12    19    261 <NA>
#13   166    186   hi
#14   273     25 <NA>
#15   246    294 <NA>
#16   227    151   hi
#17   208    306 <NA>
#18   256    211 <NA>
#19   175    188   hi
#20   202     43 <NA>
```

This vector `c('hi', NA, NA)` is repeated until end of the data.

Comment: wow perfect, just for my own knowledge whey does it require `length.out` would'nt dplyr just take care of that.  Anyways, awesome, thanks.

Comment: `dplyr` will not take care of that. In base R, it may work but only if number of rows in the data (20) is completely divisible by length of vector (3) . In this case 20 is not completely divisible by 3 so it will not work but if you take only 18 rows `temp <- temp[1:18, ]` then using `temp$t <- c('hi', NA, NA)` would work.

Comment: hi, not sure if I should start a new question or addendum the question, but is it possible instead of "hi" to get the value from "value2" instead?

Comment: I think it would be better to ask that as a new question.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I think that is the recommended protocol as well.